# j2me facebook graph api - posting image on a user wall

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, java-me, lwuit

I'm trying to post image from device on user's wall. I have found: http://codenameone.blogspot.com/2011/09/lwuit-and-facebook-api-by-chen-fishbein_18.html, but it doesn't support post image, so I wrote a simple method like this:

```
 public void postOnWallWithPhoto(String userId, String message, byte[] img) throws IOException {
    checkAuthentication();
    FacebookRESTService con = new FacebookRESTService(token, userId, FEED, true);
    con.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    con.addArgument("message", message);
    con.addArgument("type", "photo");
    con.addArgument("picture", img);
    if (slider != null) {
        SliderBridge.bindProgress(con, slider);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < responseCodeListeners.size(); i++) {
        con.addResponseCodeListener((ActionListener) elementAt(i));
    }
    current = con;
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(con);
}
```

This method is called in this way:

```
FileConnection fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open(path);
InputStream is = fc.openInputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[(int) fc.fileSize()];
is.read(b);
FaceBookAccess.getInstance().postOnWallWithPhoto(me.getId(), "test2", b);
```

After I send request, on a wall appears only text (in this example test2). In place where should be an image, there is a message: "invalid invalid".

Does anyone have idea, what I'm doing wrong? Or can someone share with me a code that will help me in posting images on a facebook wall?

Comment: There is also this other Facebook API for Java ME at http://kenai.com/projects/facebookapime/pages/Home Can you try it?

Comment: Yes I have tried this one also. It does not support posting images on a wall.

Answer (score 1):

The old LWUIT facebook login no longer works properly due to changes made by facebook to their login process.

This only works with [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) which also supports image posting in its current facebook demo.

Answer (score 1):

As we all know J2me does not provide with any in api for facebook support but there is a way we can still post images on facebook wall and i have done that.
Below i am sharing a breif procedure of how we can post images to facebook wall using j2me.

1. Get the ACCESS TOKEN from from facebook: You can do it using PHP or any third party api for getting it done(in my case i used app42(shephertz) cloud services)
2. Once you have the ACCESS TOKEN use that access Token to get the facebook userid on which you want to post the image.
3. And once you have the userId only thing left is to upload the image to facebook using 'MultiPart Request'. Below are some important statements from my code(I am not sharing my whole code because i have used third party api(app42) to get the access token and user id).

Url for facebook:

```
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + user_id + "/photos?access_token=" + accessToken;
```

image stored in byte array : byte fileBytes[];

HashTable used in multipart request(you can copy it as it is):

```
Hashtable params = new Hashtable();
params.put("custom_param", "param1");
params.put("custom_param2", "param2");
```

A class that is sending my multipart request

```
HttpMultipartRequest req = new HttpMultipartRequest(url, params, "upload_field", "original_filename.png", "image/png", fileBytes);
```

you can use the following link to refer Multipart request
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME

And once you are done with it i hope u might have successfully posted an image on facebook wall.

Happy Coding..